# LoginView with PolymerTemplate not recognizing error parameter

Tags: vaadin, query-string, vaadin-flow

I have a LoginView which I basically copied from the bakery starter project.

When I run the bakery app and try to login with wrong credentials, there appears an additional div with an error message.

However, this error message div does not appear in my view. I have since adapted the template to our Corporate Design, but I can remember that this issue already existed when the two files `LoginView.java` and `login-view.html` were still exact copies from the bakery app. I double checked that .error is not just hidden by my own css - the div.error is not existing in the DOM.

Debugging the LoginView when visiting `/login?error` (visiting `login?error=true` is the same) shows that it does not recognize any queryParameters! --> Why?

---

My App debugged:
[image: debugging screenshot]

---

Bakery App debugged:
[image: debugging screenshot 2]

---

My (Spring) Security Configuration is the same too where the login is concerned:

```
.and()
.formLogin()
.loginPage(("/login")).permitAll()
.loginProcessingUrl("/login")
.failureUrl("/login?error")
```

---

Edit: as asked for in the comments, I'll add the relevant part of the template. However, the error is 100% not in the template - as I can see with debugging that the error occurs already in the `LoginView.java` in the afterNavigation method.

```
<dom-module id="login-view">
  <template>
    <style include="shared-styles">
        .....
    </style>
        .....
            <template is="dom-if" if="[[error]]">
              <div class="error">
                <iron-icon icon="vaadin:exclamation-circle-o" class="error__icon"></iron-icon>
                <p class="error__text">
                  Der Benutzername und/oder das Passwort stimmt nicht. Bitte überprüfe deine Angaben und versuche es erneut.
                </p>
              </div>
            </template>
      ....
  </template>

  <script>
    class LoginView extends Polymer.GestureEventListeners(Polymer.Element) {
        static get is() {
            return 'login-view';
        }

        static get properties() {
            return {
                error: {
                    type: Boolean,
                    value: false
                }
            };
        }
        ......
    }
    window.customElements.define(LoginView.is, LoginView);
  </script>
</dom-module>
```

Comment: Can you show the dom-if in your template where you bind to the 'error' model parameter?

Comment: Sure, see edit. However, I think the debugging screenshots prove that the error occurs before the template comes into play (this is why I removed the template code from this post in the first place)

Comment: You're right. I think the template does not relate to it.

Comment: When I run the app locally with `liberty:run-server` (which I have been doing always) then this behaviour occurs. I have now tried to run the app locally with `spring-boot:run` and then I see the error message!

Answer (score 1):

While the question is quite old, it seems like the issue was somehow related to to the liberty server. There probably was something that prevented (?) the usage of the `?error` query parameter in this case, as the same code works on other servers.

If the issue still persists and can be reproduced in project that can be shared, you should create an issue to the [vaadin/spring](https://github.com/vaadin/spring/issues/new) repository. The `LoginView` implementation should not made based on a `PolymerTemplate` anymore, as there is a server side Java integrations that can be used, like the `LoginOverlay` component.
Also starting from Vaadin 20, there is a Spring security configuration class `VaadinWebSecurityConfigurerAdapter` which provides helpers for setting up Spring security with Vaadin apps. There is more details on the [documentation](https://vaadin.com/docs/latest/flow/integrations/spring/view-based-access-control/#security-configuration-class).